# Log4j: как понизить дефолтную версию?

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

У меня проект на Gretty. Сейчас проект готовится к деплою на внешний сервер. Выяснилось, что на внешнем сервере стоит какая-то древняя версия jetty (вроде, ниже 9.4), которая не работает с JEP-238. А последние версии log4j как раз являются JEP-238. При попытке запуска приложения на jetty выплёвывает довольно известную ошибку:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311295/error-scanning-entry-module-info-class-when-starting-jetty-server

Варианта, по сути, два:

1. Поднять версию jetty, что сейчас не представляется возможным
2. Опустить версию log4j.

Проблема в том, log4j не задаётся как явная зависимость, а подтаскивается какой-то другой. И непонятно, какой. Вот build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id "org.gretty" version "2.2.0"
}
group 'ru.example'
version '0.1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

ext {
    SPRING_VERSION = '5.1.0.RELEASE'
    JUNIT_VERSION = '5.3.1'
    JACKSON_VERSION = '2.9.7'
    LOMBOK_VERSION = '1.18.2'
}

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
}

gretty {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    contextPath = "/"
}

dependencies {
//    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: LOMBOK_VERSION
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: LOMBOK_VERSION
    compileOnly group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-endpoints-deps', version: '1.9.65'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: SPRING_VERSION
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: SPRING_VERSION
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: SPRING_VERSION
    compile ("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.1.0.RELEASE") {
        exclude(module:'spring-web')
    }
    compile ("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile ("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:4.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.mchange', name: 'c3p0', version: '0.9.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: JACKSON_VERSION
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: JACKSON_VERSION
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: JACKSON_VERSION
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '26.0-jre'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
//    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: JUNIT_VERSION
//    testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: JUNIT_VERSION
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: JUNIT_VERSION
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.22.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: SPRING_VERSION
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path-assert', version: '2.4.0'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
}
```

External Libraries хранят версию log4j 2.10.0, а надо поставить примерно 2.8.
Я не могу определить, из какой зависимости нужно выпилить log4j, чтобы явно задать зависимость. Если есть решение, подскажите, как это сделать.

Comment: Таск `dependencies` покажет всё дерево зависимостей, что позволит добавить директивы `exclude` для транзитивных зависимостей нежелательной версии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, выпилили `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` и добавили нужные зависимости отдельно. Неправильный `lombok` был там.